# Twitter API Limit Mystery

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-search

I am mining some tweets from twitter via twitter 4j. My code is running on a server and until yesterday I had no issues however I have recently started to get this error.

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanyll explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-updatng). message - Missing or invalid url parameter. code - 195
```

When I run the same code locally I cannot reproduce this error and I am allowed to mine tweets just fine. Furthermore I am confident that I am working within Twitter's rate limits and all I am accessing is tweets. I am not updating anything in my code. Finally, when I wait until the reset time and run the code on my server again, the same error occurs without allowing me to mine any tweets.

I have looked online and cannot find a solution to this problem. Has anybody encountered something similar? Please help.

Comment: Could you please provide which version of twitter4J API you are using?

Comment: I am using the most recent snapshop build. I think it's 3.0.6.

Comment: Please show the code